# Forgot Password? - sends email with plaintext password

Tags: web-application, passwords

A "reputable" education company that my university utilizes for it's Physics
course online materials sent my plaintext password in an email after using the `Forgot Password?` tool.

I know that this is bad practice and is a little disconcerting coming from  a prominent "reputable" corporation.

What I want to know is if it would be prudent or worthwhile to contact the company and ask/inform them about this issue to see if they're willing to address it?

Should I take any additional precautions on their website other than using a completely unique password?

Comment: There's 2 things wrong with this: a) they have access to your password (its not hashed), b) they send without encryption. This is just very bad practice -.-

Comment: What's really bad is that you (or the casual user) are likely to reuse the same password/username combo on several sites despite best practice, relying (or hoping) that it's not a problem -- after all nobody can see these since you're logging in over SSL anyway (and passwords are salted/hashed, so website A and website B have different hashes stored, though most users don't know that). Right? And now, _surprise_, it turns out your PW is stored _plaintext_ and has been been publicly visible on the network and on your mail server (and has been, like all mail, forwarded to malicious people).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When someone has forgotten his password, there is not much to build on to allow for a "password reset". Using email is weak but there is little choice.

The problem is that they send you *your* password as plaintext, which means that they have your password stored somewhere, unprotected. [This is bad](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2011/11/why-passwords-should-be-hashed/). If you are willing to point them out publicly and mock them, then you may share your experience on [this site](http://plaintextoffenders.com/); however, people in general don't react well to mockery. Sending them an email before *is* worthwhile:

- If anything else, it will boost your own ego. Playing the role of the nice guy of the story is always elating.
- They are an *education* company working with a university: they should nominally know the value of knowledge and be open to suggestions.
- They are an education company working with a *university*: their users are *student*, who are, security-wise, a scary bunch: they are young, not completely rational, prone to poke at things for the fun of it, they have time on their hands, and they have access to a lot of computing power. This highlights the need for really good security.

**Anyway**, reusing passwords is bad. You should *already* be using a specific password for their site. By emailing your password back, they *demonstrate* sloppy security, but it would be unrealistic to assume that average Web sites do better. One password per site is the rule. Of course this implies managing a lot of passwords; this can be taken care of with some password manager software like [this one](http://keepass.info/).

Answer (score 3):

I definitely think it is worth telling the company how you feel regarding how they handle your privacy. I am sure management often times doesn't know the technical details or implications of password storage policy.

I have run into this twice with mixed results:

- T-Mobile: They text you a plaintext password to your account portal when you submit your telephone # to the lost password link. They were not interested in hearing about the problem.
- Jimmy Johns: The forgot password form was sending plain text passwords via email. I questioned the practice, and they apologized and immediately implemented a password reset code instead. I don't know whether they started hashing passwords.

It is horrible practice, and I encourage anyone to put pressure on companies doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you might as well tell them but don't get your hopes up. In my experience, if the entire IT department doesn't care about/understand security, an email from an outsider won't change that.

Using a throw away password is a good idea. If your account being compromised could affect your life outside of this site a better idea would be to not create an account at all.

If you do send an email, I would suggest sending it to the IT department as well as the CEO's office. You might have a better chance of getting something done if they are worried about getting in trouble.